# Flutter contains always return true

Tags: flutter

I may missunderstand something.

_thisEvent.eventKidsPayed is a List that contains documentID strings.
kidsSnapshot.data.documents[index].documentID will give us a string.

_thisEvent.eventKidsPayed is currently EMPTY there is nothing in the list.

```
bool _payed = false;
if (_thisEvent.eventKidsPayed.contains(kidsSnapshot
    .data.documents[index].documentID)) {
       _payed = true;
    }
```

It's always returning true. Why ?

Comment: Are you sure it is empty? Suggest you put a couple of print statements before the 'if' to show the contents of thisEvent.eventKidsPayed and kidsSnapshot.data.documents[index].documentID

Comment: you might be putting `bool _payed = false;` inside `build` method. Put it outside `build` method.

Comment: Found the solution the problem was somewhere else in the code(i posted it as answer here). Thanks for your times guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my Insert and Delete and not with my .contains
Sorry all for disturbing and time lost.

I was doing this by error (this is not the code but the logic)

```
If(value) //true if contains
  array remove
else
  array union
```

So it was totally wrong, I fixed doing If(!value). Sorry for this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `setState` to change bool. Follow the below code. You need to use `StatefulWidget` for using `setState`.

```
bool _payed = false;
if (_thisEvent.eventKidsPayed.contains(kidsSnapshot
    .data.documents[index].documentID)) {

 setState(() {
  _payed = true;
 });
}
```

Comment: i was not trying to display the bool to the screen but in a print. If i print result after the IF it's always return me true. Even if the list is empty and the string is 100 char longs. Thats what i don't understand.

Comment: Found the solution the problem was somewhere else in the code(i posted it as answer here). Thanks for your time Salim.